# Cannot resolve symbol 'google' for Cloud Vision API

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to get Google Cloud Vision API working with Java in IntelliJ. I've followed all the steps at https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries. I'm running the following code, just trying to import the packages I need and when I scroll over google, it is underlined in red and says 'cannot resolve symbol google'. How do I fix this?

[code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GlRg.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error shown in your screenshot usually happens when an external dependency could not be loaded.

Please make sure you accurately followed the steps in the [Install the Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#install_the_client_library) section of the guide you followed, in the Java tab of the widget.

From the screenshot I can not really tell what build settings you configured for the IntelliJ project. If you chose no build tools or the regular Ant setup, it might be easier for you to re-setup a project based on either Maven or Gradle.
With Gradle and Maven it is pretty straightforward to add the dependency to the project as described in the guide, otherwise you will have to download all the dependency libraries yourself and add them to your project folder and build environment manually as files.

If you did already use Gradle or Maven for your project, and did follow the guide but it still shows the error, then it's usually a case of IntelliJ not loading those changes yet.
In that case you can fix it by selecting your Gradle or Maven tab in Intellij, and clicking the re-import button (looks like a refresh icon from browsers) to reload the configuration, usually triggering a download of missing dependencies.
Otherwise you can also trigger a full build with running the `gradle build` or `mvn compile` targets, which also should download all configured missing dependencies.